# How to load css file after a certain css file

Tags: plugin-development

I want to know using wp_register_style function.

```
wp_register_style('bmg-comp-listing-jquery-timepicker-css-public', plugins_url('css/public/jquery.timepicker.min.css', __FILE__),array('plsh-style-css'));
```

I tried to pass it like that but its not working. What should the array contain?

Answer (score 0):

You have three options to enqueue a CSS after one another. You can either:

### Increase the priority of the hook

You can set the hook's priority as follows:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'some_function', 999);
function some_function() {
    wp_register_style('bmg- ... -public', plugins_url('...', __FILE__),array('plsh-style'));
    wp_enqueue_style('bmg- ... -public');
}
```

This comes in handy when you are using a plugin to enqueue a CSS and do not want to modify the templates, or vice versa.

### Enqueue them in order

If you have multiple CSS files you want to enqueue, simply use them in order:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'some_function', 999);
function some_function() {
    // First register them
    wp_register_style( 'bmg- ... -public', plugins_url('...', __FILE__) );
    wp_register_style( 'plsh-style', plugins_url('...', __FILE__) );
    // Then enqueue them in order
    wp_enqueue_style( 'plsh-style' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bmg- ... -public' );
}
```

This will cause `my-style` to be enqueued *after* `my-style`.

### Set the depandancies

The third argument of `wp_register_style()` is an array that indicates the dependencies for this stylesheet. Dependent stylesheets will be loaded before this stylesheet. You might as well want to first register the dependency handler. Take a look at the relevant [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) page about this function.

**Note:** The real handler name does not usually contain `-css`. This is added automatically by WordPress while enqueuing style. You might want to use `plsh-style` instead of `plsh-style-css`. So, This:

```
wp_register_style('bmg- ... -public', plugins_url('...', __FILE__),array('plsh-style-css'));
```

Should be turned to this:

```
wp_register_style('bmg- ... -public', plugins_url('...', __FILE__),array('plsh-style'));
```

I've removed the links and names to make the code fit in a single line.

Comment: I saw in the codex but not getting idea of how to? I am looking out for using depandancies. Can you give an example as to what I should pass to the array. Is it file name or id. I am not getting, please help

Comment: Please try the note I just added. This might solve your problem.

Comment: I tried it but whats happening is my css is coming after the other css but the other css file is also going on top which should not happen. I mean the other css has changed its order. :(

Comment: Ok so it's half done. How is the other CSS registered? And which one of the methods of these 3 did you use?

Comment: I am developing plugin where I need the css of this plugin to include after the theme css or the bootstrap css of that theme. I have used all  3 methods now but I dont see the result as needed. Actually I am using jquery timepicker so i need this timepicker css to appear after bootstrap css of the theme.

Comment: Then the first method should work for you. Increase the priority to 1000, and then register your script. Maybe even a higher number, like 1100. This does enqueue your css after the theme with a good chance, but don't use the dependency in this method, just a simple register and enqueue.

Comment: the bootstrap css is in the middle. If i use the first method than its placing time-picker css last.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62978/discussion-between-abhilash-narayan-and-jack-johansson).